# How to get values from dynamically generated text box separately?

Tags: jquery, dynamic

```
$.ajax({            
  type: "POST",
  contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
  dataType:'json',
  url: 'generatequotations',
  data: JSON.stringify(),
  success: function(result) {
    //  alert("success"); 
    console.log(result);
    $.each(result, function(i, item) { 
      tr = $('<tr/>');   
      tr.append($("<td/>").html('<input type="text" name="unit_price" id="unit_price"/>'));
      tr.append($("<td/>").html('<input type="text" readonly="true" name="total" id="total"/>'));
      $('#tbl_items').append(tr);
    });   
  }
});

<body>
<table id="tbl_items"></table>
</body>
```

Suppose the above code will generate 10 'unit_price' text box in a table, what i need is i want to get values of this 10 textbox's separately for further calculation. Help me geeks...

Link to the screen shot http://oi62.tinypic.com/255hslc.jpg

The two rows are dynamically generated i want to get each textbox('unit_price') inside corresponding total('total') textboxes

Comment: you will need to write the code after inputs are loaded.that is after appending tr.

Comment: After appending tr i got a table with dynamically generated textboxes. I need to get values of those dynamic textboxes separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your textbox selector from `id` to `class` because you have to take multiple value.

```
<input type="text" name="unit_price" class="unit_price"/>
<input type="text" name="unit_price" class="total"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
total = 0;
$(".unit_price").each(function(){
   //Find total column and put unit_price value in total column
   $(this).closest(".total").val($(this).val());  
});
```

Comment: Will this work? You do not converting value from string to number.

Comment: Sure. gst = $(this).parent().parent().find(".gst").val(); this way could i get the value of gst within the same function?

Comment: Yes you can find `.gst` value within same function.

Comment: do you want to add `gst` in `total column`?

Comment: Yeah i want to add unit_price with gst and display it in total field.

Comment: @Sadikhasan how could i get unit_price of both the rows in a button click like an array or some other way? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value using two different ways.

First: When you are adding a textbox to row at that time make it's id as "id"+ i, this will provide different id to each textbox, same thing can be applied to row also.

Second: If you are providing same id to all Textboxes (which you are currently doing) then you can find it's value using "this". $(this).closest('input'), $(this).siblings(),$(this).parent() all these will help you to get value of Textbox.

Whatever method you try, try it on console of Browser, specially on Chrome, this will help you in great manner.

Comment: Can you give a simple example on your first solution :)

Comment: O.k, I am giving you a small e.g.
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
<input id=txt+"i" type="textbox" />
}
Now this code will create 10 textboxes whose id will be txt1, txt2-------txt10.